# Access key values within an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oracle-call-interface

I am having trouble with associative arrays and sql queries. The thing is I have a query which has its lines stored into an array like this:

```
$query21 = "SELECT PROCESSO, DATAMSG, CATEGORIA_DESC, VALOR, CRITICO FROM TABLEX";
$result21 = oci_parse($connect, $query21);
oci_execute($result21);

$c1=array();
while($res21 = oci_fetch_array($result21))  {
    $c1[]=$res21;
}
print_r($c1);
```

This code prints this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1647306
            [PROCESSO] => 1647306
            [1] => 2015-04-27 23
            [DATAMSG] => 2015-04-27 23
            [2] => ECG_HR                        
            [CATEGORIA_DESC] => ECG_HR                        
            [3] => 59
            [VALOR] => 59
            [4] => 1
            [CRITICO] => 1
       )
)
```

The problem is I don't know why it is repeating the results twice. I expected the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PROCESSO] => 1647306
            [DATAMSG] => 2015-04-27 23                       
            [CATEGORIA_DESC] => ECG_HR                        
            [VALOR] => 59
            [CRITICO] => 1
       )
)
```

Also how can I access the `[PROCESSO]`,...,`[CRITICO]` key values? I have tried but can only access the `$c1['0']` key which holds the array, though I need the values inside.

Comment: Instead of `oci_fetch_array` use `oci_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default [**oci_fetch_array()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) uses `OCI_BOTH` fetching mode; that means it returns an array with both associative and numeric indices. You may either explicitly switch numeric indexing off with...

```
oci_fetch_array($result21, OCI_ASSOC)
```

... or just use [**oci_fetch_assoc()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php) instead.

You might also consider dropping `while` altogether and just using [**oci_fetch_all()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) in fill-by-row mode:

```
oci_fetch_all($result21, $c1, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```

In either case, you'll be able to iterate over those arrays with the same techniques you iterate over any other one. For example:

```
foreach ($c1 as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' is ', $value, '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok nice, I did that and it solved the repeating issue. But how can I access the values of keys [PROCESSO],etc. I can only access $c1['0'] as I said in my post.

Comment: `$c1['0']['PROCESSO']`. You can iterate over all the keys with `foreach($c1[0] as $key => $value)` as well.

Comment: I tried to print like this but didn't work `print_r ($c1['0']['PROCESSO']);`. Also if I had more than one array how could I do this? Scan through arrays [0],[1],etc and get the values inside.

Comment: Because `$c1['0']['PROCESSO']` is not an array, `$c1['0']` is, so you can `print_r` the latter, but should `echo` or `print` the former. You'll have to iterate over `$c1` array.